# Does `UITextContentType` work in 3rd party apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitextfield

I'm trying to get `UITextField` to auto complete informations like addresses and zip code but it's not working.

Here's the code:

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
textField.textContentType = UITextContentTypeStreetAddressLine1;
```

I could only get this to work with `UITextContentTypeEmailAddress` and `UITextContentTypeName`.

Yes, I'm running this on a real device and have a completely filled out contact card for myself. The autocomplete works for me in Safari, so I know my information is correctly input.